# animate canvas up and down based on cylinder height and variable value which i enter in the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

Animating canvas (line) up and down based on the variable value.

Here I have added variable name position. Default my line will be in bottom of the cylinder. When I enter the value as 20 it has move up and vice verca  if I enter the value as 15 it has to come down like that  0 - 100. So what I tried was I created a variable inside a new function call

```
function animatecurve()
{
    var position = 0;
    alert("position " + position);
    var bottomcylin = $('#canvas').position().top + $('#canvas').outerHeight(true);
    alert("cylinder bottom" + bottomcylin);
    if (position1 > 0) {
    alert("inside position" +  position1);
    $('#myCanvas').animate({top:"-=10px",}, 300);
} else {
    $('#myCanvas').animate({top:"0px",}, 300);
}
}
```

Here I have found outerheight of the cylinder. It should not go beyond the cylinder if i enter the value 30 in the position my curve has to move towards top of the cylinder.

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/LyTt2/)

Please guide me.

Regards
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/BG6p2/, maybe this is what you are looking for

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="500"></canvas>
<input type="text" id="level" placeholder="type value here %" />
```

Javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    input  = document.getElementById('level');

//helpers
ctx.drawEllipse = function(x, y, radius, color, colorBorder){
    this.fillStyle   = '#000';
    this.strokeStyle = '#000';

    this.save();

    this.scale(2, 1);

    this.beginPath();

    this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

    this.restore();

    this.closePath();

    if(color) {
        this.fillStyle = color;
        this.fill();

        if(colorBorder) this.strokeStyle = color;
    }

    this.stroke();
}

ctx.drawLine = function(startX, startY, endX, endY, color){
    if(color) this.strokeStyle = color;

    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
    ctx.stroke();
};

/**
* @params
* @param x                    - top left x coordinate
* @param y                    - top left y coordinate
* @param radius               - ellipsis radius
* @param height               - cylinder height
* @param liquidColor          - inner liquid color
* @param liquidSunnySideColor - liquid surface color
* @param liquidLevel          - liquid level
**/
ctx.drawCylinder = function(x, y, radius, height, liquidColor, liquidSunnySideColor,liquidLevel){
    //do not spill
    liquidLevel = Math.min(height, liquidLevel);

    //draw liquid inner body
    ctx.fillStyle = liquidColor;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y + (height - liquidLevel), x + radius * 4, liquidLevel);
    //console.log(x, y);

    //bottom cap
    ctx.drawEllipse(x, y + height, radius, liquidLevel ? liquidColor : false);

    //liquid level
    ctx.drawEllipse(x, y + (height - liquidLevel), radius, liquidLevel ? liquidSunnySideColor : false, true);

    ctx.drawEllipse(x, y + height, radius);

    //top cap
    ctx.drawEllipse(x, y, radius);

    //left border
    ctx.drawLine(x, y, x, y + height, '#000');

    //right border
    ctx.drawLine(x + radius * 4, y, x + radius * 4, y + height, '#000');
}

var renderLoop = window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame,
    //workers
    _fps          = 60,
    _speed        = 1,
    _currentLevel = 0,
    _maxLevel     = 0,
    _renderTime   = 0,
    _render,
    time,

    //cylinder
    x      = 100,
    y      = 100,
    radius = 50,
    height = 200;

_render = function(){
    time = window.performance.now();

    if(time - _renderTime > 1000 / _fps){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 500);

        //only positive values
        _currentLevel = Math.max(0, _currentLevel);

        if(_currentLevel > _maxLevel) _currentLevel -= _speed;
        if(_currentLevel < _maxLevel) _currentLevel += _speed;

        ctx.drawCylinder(x, y, radius, height, '#90C94D', '#BBED80', _currentLevel);

        _renderTime = time;
    }

    renderLoop(_render);
}

_render();

input.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    //only positive values
    _maxLevel = Math.max(0, height * Math.min(1, this.value / 100));
});
```

Comment: Hi @Dart thank you so much for the code that you shared it was looking awesome I will use it in my next project for sure but right now what i want is just need to change the direction of the fill

Comment: @Mahadevan if you mean move orange line along with the fill look here http://jsfiddle.net/LyTt2/3/, i have moved myCurse method call inside draw()

Comment: Hi @Dart thank you so much for the code if you see when we enter some value it start filling from back side (Look) but What I want it has to start from front side filling

Comment: @Mahadevan ok, let me try again, you want - orange line to move up/down when liquid level changes. If so take a look here myCurve function() http://jsfiddle.net/LyTt2/7/